# Saving a user/account to be stored and passed around app

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

I am using AFNetworking 2.0 and Mantle in order to connect to an API and return a user account.

My plan is to call the function that gets the user data in the `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method. I will then [encode the data and save the user into NSUserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2315972/1813167)

Is this the best way to approach this task? What alternatives are there? (I'd like to stay away from creating singletons)

---

**UPDATE**

Some code to maybe help show what I am thinking in my head:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSData *encodedUserData = [defaults objectForKey:@"currentUser"];
if (encodedUserData) {
    self.currentUser = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedUserData];
} else {
    NSLog(@"No current user");
    // Show login ViewController
}
```

Comment: using singleton class or [uiapplication shared application delegate method]

Comment: I should have probably said, I want to try and stay away from creating singleton classes.

Comment: then app delegate shared application method\

Comment: Yeah, I think that fits in pretty well with the code I have just added

Comment: As long as your object conforms to NSCoding, you can use that approach without a problem. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259326/storing-nsnull-null-values-in-nsuserdefaults-from-json-serialization-causes/26259586#26259586

Comment: but app delegate shared application method does not holding the value in the long time , if ur app is gone on background, it remove the values

Comment: Anbu: Can't I just then re-get the user in `applicationDidBecomeActive`?

Comment: `NSSecureCoding` is recommended (iOS 6 and up).

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to get the user account every time user launches the app, then you don't need to store it in NSUserDefaults. Just use a singleton or static object to store it as your model object type.

```
static Account *_userAccount = nil;
+ (Account*)userAccount {
    return _userAccount;
}
+ (void)setUserAccount:(Account*)account {
    _userAccount = account;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I maybe didn't word the question in the best way but I have just added a little code snippet which maybe helps explain it a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSUserDefaults for this purpose and can access it through out application.

```
// to save data in userdefaults

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"your object" forKey:@"your key"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


// for getting saved data from User defaults

NSData *encodedUserData = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"your key"];
if (encodedUserData) {
    self.currentUser = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:encodedUserData];
} else {
    NSLog(@"No current user");
    // Show login ViewController
}
```